# strptime to strftime for day of the week

Tags: c, time, strftime, strptime

I'm using the following format string with strptime

```
// Populates input_tm with an input string of Monthname Date, Year
strptime(input_string, "%B %d, %Y", &input_tm);

// Output the day of the week from input_tm
strftime(output_string, TIME_BUFSZ, "%A", &input_tm);
```

After the call to strftime the output_string contains "?"

What additional fields to I need to populate in input_tm for strftime to work?

**Edit:**

Figured it out by looking at the source of `strftime`

The required struct field is `tm_wday`.

If I set `input_tm.tm_wday` to something manually before the call to `strftime` it gives me an output.

So now my question is, is there a standard C function that will compute the weekday from a given date?

Comment: It's better to provide a minimal example that **can compile**.

Comment: FYI, `strftime` and `strptime` do very little in the way of computation; most formats merely directly store or directly use one field of `struct tm`. Only the week-based-year ones and maybe a few other obscure formats actually compute any *derived* data. The specification for `strftime` tells which fields it uses. For `strptime`, the specification is much less clear. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me — the call to `mktime()` resolves the problems you got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

enum { TIME_BUFSZ = 256 };

int main(void)
{
    char input_string[] = "November 18, 2014";
    char output_string[TIME_BUFSZ];

    struct tm input_tm = { 0 };
    char *end = strptime(input_string, "%B %d, %Y", &input_tm);
    if (*end != '\0')
        printf("Unused data: [[%s]]\n", end);

    printf("tm_year = %d; tm_mon = %d; tm_mday = %d; tm_wday = %d; tm_yday = %d\n",
            input_tm.tm_year, input_tm.tm_mon, input_tm.tm_mday,
            input_tm.tm_wday, input_tm.tm_yday);
    time_t t0 = mktime(&input_tm);
    printf("tm_year = %d; tm_mon = %d; tm_mday = %d; tm_wday = %d; tm_yday = %d\n",
            input_tm.tm_year, input_tm.tm_mon, input_tm.tm_mday,
            input_tm.tm_wday, input_tm.tm_yday);
    printf("t0 = %lld\n", (long long)t0);

    size_t nbytes = strftime(output_string, TIME_BUFSZ, "%A", &input_tm);

    printf("in: [[%s]]\n", input_string);
    printf("out (%zu): [[%s]]\n", nbytes, output_string);
    return 0;
}
```

Example run (GCC 4.8.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.2 Mavericks):

```
tm_year = 114; tm_mon = 10; tm_mday = 18; tm_wday = 0; tm_yday = 0
tm_year = 114; tm_mon = 10; tm_mday = 18; tm_wday = 2; tm_yday = 321
t0 = 1416297600
in: [[November 18, 2014]]
out (7): [[Tuesday]]
```

This agrees with the result from `cal 11 2014`:

```
   November 2014
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                   1
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22
23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30
```

Comment: Awesome, I found out about `mktime` just before you posted this. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Note to readers, it's critical that the tm struct be initialized with 0s before calling `mktime`. This might mean using `calloc`.

Comment: Actually, its crucial that it is zeroed before calling `strptime()`; if you zero it after calling `strptime()` and before calling `mktime()`, you'll be told about 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00.  Note that the very first version of my code omitted the initializer from `struct tm input_tm = { 0 };`, but I fixed that before the grace period was up.  Yes, you could use `calloc()` and `free()`; you could also use `memset()`.